# в чём разница между статической и динамической библиотекой?

Tags: qt, qt5

Подключил к проекту PCANBasic.dll в папке про и подклучил заголовочный файл PCANBasic.h .

```
HEADERS += \
        mainwindow.h \
        PCANBasic.h
....
LIBS += \
        PCANBasic.dll
```

Всё заработало, но вопрос остался, а что я подключил ***статическую*** или ***динамическую*** библиотеку ??

п.с. *Поделанно в бесплатной версии Qt*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В общем я подключил ***динамическую*** библиотеку.

---

Статическая представляет собой собрание *.obj-файлов библиотеки в *.lib, который мы можем, указав линкеру, прицепить к нашей программе в момент компиляции. Содержимой библиотеки, как всегда, описывается в хэдерах, которые распространяются вместе с *.lib .  ***На выходе мы получим одинокий исполняемый файл вашей программы (.exe).*** А  ещё статические библиотеки увеличивают размер кода в двоичном формате. Они всегда загружаются, и любая версия кода, скомпилированного вами, - это версия запускаемого кода :3.

Динамическая линковка выполняется средствами платформы (операционной системы) в процессе работы программы. Все так же у нас в руках *.lib и *.h файлы, однако, теперь к ним добавляется *.dll (*.so для Linux). *.lib-файл теперь содержит только вызовы к *.dll, где лежат непосредственно алгоритмы и которые вызываются уже на ходу, а не компилируются. Потому теперь у нас *.exe + *.dll . Несколько программ могут использовать один *.dll одновременно, тем самым не занимая оперативную память одинаковыми кусками и сами программы меньше размером. Так, например, работают многие драйверы и графические библиотеки (DirectX и OpenGL). Однако, сейчас это не такая актуальная проблема, тянут недостатки - несовместимости версий, отсутствие нужных библиотек, ад зависимостей для установки приложений (работая в Linux с графическим окружением Gnome (основанной на библиотеке GTK+) если скачать малюсенький текстовый редактор Kate для ГО KDE (основанной на Qt), то придется тянуть этот-самый Qt на десятки мегабайт). Потому, сейчас рекомендуют не увлекаться динамической линковкой и стараться связывать программы статически. Да и *.dll придется таскать с собой :3

[Вот где это прочитал](http://words-are-dust.blogspot.com/2013/10/dll-lib.html)

Comment: _"сейчас рекомендуют не увлекаться динамической линковкой и стараться связывать программы статически"_ это кем рекомендуется?

Comment: @mkkik [тут](http://words-are-dust.blogspot.com/2013/10/dll-lib.html)

Comment: Сомнительная рекомендация без указания области применения.

Comment: @mkkik извините я не столь хорош в программировании. Может проще чтоб вы отредактировали мой ответ ???